# run bash command in python and display on browser

Tags: php, python, html, bash

I have this simple python code:

```
import os
#os.system ("bash -c 'ls /home/'")
script = "ls /home/user/"
os.system(script)
```

How do I use PHP to display the output?

Comment: This question is WAY too broad. You haven't told us a single piece of information about your website.

Comment: Use subprocess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Comment: You could use `cherrypy` or `django` to deal with webpages and web servers.

Comment: No website yet, just testing and learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with HTML, but using PHP first you can output to HTML from a python script using shell_exec e.g.

```
<?php $output = shell_exec("python scriptName.py");
echo '<p>'.$output.'<p>'; ?>
```